define condition while piping a tibble
Is there any way to define a condition so as I can use it several time while piping a tibble?
data <- tibble(age = c(25, 30, 18, 40), income = c(50000, 70000, 35000, 80000))

filter_condition <- (age >= 25 & income > 50000)

mod_data <- data %>%
mutate(
   group = ifelse(filter_condition, "High Earner", "Other"),
   discount = ifelse(filter_condition, 0.1, 0.05)           
)

or alternatively assign values to different columns based on the same condition?

?rlang::args_data_masking and ?dplyr::filter get ypu started.

You can define the condition like this and then it will work.
filter_condition <- (data$age >= 25 & data$income > 50000)


As mentioned in the comments by @Friede, you know that age and income are columns in data, but R does not know that. One potential solution that is unique to tibble is you can define new columns based on previously defined columns:
data <- tibble(age = c(25, 30, 18, 40), 
       income = c(50000, 70000, 35000, 80000),
       filter_condition = age >= 25 & income > 50000)

You could also define it in your mutate statement:
data %>%
  mutate(
    filter_condition = age >= 25 & income > 50000,
    group = ifelse(filter_condition, "High Earner", "Other"),
    discount = ifelse(filter_condition, 0.1, 0.05)           
  )


@fred it is easier to help if you post a question and a reproducible example that is more similar to your situation.

You could define an expression and inject it into the function call
filter_condition <- rlang::expr(age >= 25 & income > 50000)
data %>%
  mutate(
    group = ifelse(!!filter_condition, "High Earner", "Other"),
    discount = ifelse(!!filter_condition, 0.1, 0.05)           
  )

or create a function that pulls from the current data
filter_condition <- function() with(pick(c(age, income)), (age >= 25 & income > 50000))
data %>%
  mutate(
    group = ifelse(filter_condition(), "High Earner", "Other"),
    discount = ifelse(filter_condition(), 0.1, 0.05)           
  )

Both of these methods will work will with group_by()

I still consider my question unsolved as all suggestions defined the filter condition before piping. I'm looking for defining conditions over columns that will be created while piping and that will be applied several times. Any clues are appreciated.

This code solves the problem posted in the question. If you have some other requirements where this would fail, maybe ask a new question. At the end of the day you need to build a valid R expression that can be executed.

Similar to the solution of @MrFlick, but simply defining your conditions as character and then using !! operator in combination with rlang's parse_expr(). Same approach comes in handy for use with filter().
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tibble)
library(rlang)

data <- tibble(
  age = c(25, 30, 18, 40), 
  income = c(50000, 70000, 35000, 80000)
)

filter_condition <- "age >= 25 & income > 50000"

mod_data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    group = ifelse(!! parse_expr(filter_condition), "High Earner", "Other"),
    discount = ifelse(!! parse_expr(filter_condition), 0.1, 0.05)           
  )
mod_data
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>     age income group       discount
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1    25  50000 Other           0.05
#> 2    30  70000 High Earner     0.1 
#> 3    18  35000 Other           0.05
#> 4    40  80000 High Earner     0.1

Created on 2024-06-12 with reprex v2.1.0
